# Why is "...seem as an underwater museum" wrong?

Tags: phrase-usage

> People looked for an unusual dive in what **might be called** an underwater mining museum.

Why can't the bold part be substituted by "seem as"?
Since seem is a linking verb meaning "to give the impression of being or doing sth " and "as" is a proposition meaning "used to describe sb/sth appearing to be sb/sth else," why couldn't them combined together to compare the place of an unusual dive as an underwater mining?

Comment: "Seems as" is just wrong in this context - I presume you have been told that in order to ask. You could say "*seems to be*". If you question is just asking "is this correct" then I'm afraid it is off-topic unless you can explain further why you are confused about the usage?

Comment: @ Astralbee, I've made it more specific, please teach me why "seem as " is wrong in this context.

Comment: Because _seem as_ is not English. Any "explanation" will simply be restating this in more complicated terms. Languages are as they are, not as somebody thinks they should be. _Seem_ happens to require a to-infinitive clause, an adjectival phrase, or (rarely) a noun phrase. It is not followed by _as_.

Comment: "Seem like", not "seem as".

Comment: @ColinFine It doesn't *seem as* though you have considered every possibility.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems:

First of all, as you point out, "seem" is a linking verb. It means "*to appear to the observation or understanding*". But to *whose* understanding? In your example, it is the "people", and you speak about them in the past tense because they '*looked*' for a dive. So, the issue with "seem" is that you have the tense wrong. It should be "**seemed**:

> People **looked** for an unusual dive in what **seemed** an underwater mining museum.

Secondly, your suggested use of "as" is wrong. We use "as" in a number of ways but none fit this context. The way you suggest using it seems like a comparison... just as I made a comparison using 'seems like' there. You *could* use it to draw a comparison like this:

> People looked for an unusual dive in what **seemed like** an underwater mining museum.

We would only use "seemed as" in this way if mentioning a specific quality of the object, for example:

> People looked for an unusual dive in what **seemed as vast and fascinating as** an underwater mining museum.

However, rather than *compare* it to something, if you want to say that it actually appeared to be something from the perspective of the onlookers, the best rendition would probably be:

> People looked for an unusual dive in what **seemed to be** an underwater mining museum.